# grep "output of cat command - every line" in a different file

Tags: shell, grep, cat

Sorry title of this question is little confusing but I couldnt think of anything else.
I am trying to do something like this

```
cat fileA.txt | grep `awk '{print $1}'` fileB.txt
```

fileA contains 100 lines while fileB contains 100 million lines.

What I want is get id from fileA, grep that id in a different file-fileB and print that line.

```
e.g fileA.txt
1234
1233

e.g.fileB.txt
1234|asdf|2012-12-12
5555|asdd|2012-11-12
1233|fvdf|2012-12-11
```

Expected output is

```
1234|asdf|2012-12-12
1233|fvdf|2012-12-11
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

awk alone can do that job well:

```
awk -F'|' 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next;}$1 in a' fileA fileB
```

see the test:

```
kent$  head a b
==> a <==
1234
1233

==> b <==
1234|asdf|2012-12-12
5555|asdd|2012-11-12
1233|fvdf|2012-12-11

kent$  awk -F'|' 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next;}$1 in a' a b
1234|asdf|2012-12-12
1233|fvdf|2012-12-11
```

**EDIT**

add explanation:

```
-F'|'  #| as field separator (fileA)
'NR==FNR{a[$0];next;} #save lines in fileA in array a
 $1 in a  #if $1(the 1st field) in fileB in array a, print the current line from FileB
```

for further details I cannot explain here, sorry. for example how awk handle two files, what is NR and what is FNR.. I suggest that try this awk line in case the accepted answer didn't work for you. If you want to dig a little bit deeper, read some awk tutorials.

Comment: +1 This should be the accepted answer, as `grep -f` will inadvertently match up things like `1234` and `11234`, for example.

Comment: @Kent would you mind explaining 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next;}$1 in a'

Comment: I am trying to figure out if I want to do a grep in a particular column... grep -f wont work.

Comment: @priyank short explanation added.

Answer (score 11):

Getting rid of `cat` and `awk` altogether:

```
grep -f fileA.txt fileB.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

If the id's are on distinct lines you could use the `-f` option in `grep` as such:

```
cut -d "|" -f1 < fileB.txt | grep -F -f fileA.txt
```

The `cut` command will ensure that only the first field is searched for in the pattern searching using `grep`.

From the man page:

```
-f FILE, --file=FILE
Obtain patterns from FILE, one per line.  
The empty file contains zero patterns, and therefore matches nothing.
(-f is specified by POSIX.)
```

Comment: @Kent I guess we will have to use `cut` too.

Comment: I think your grep needs -F too. you don't want line in fileA to be regex pattern right?

Comment: @Kent Aw, good catch. Or use `fgrep` but that is not as available.

Comment: OP has accepted the answer. If he was not coming back for better solution, the grep worked with his "100 million lines" fileB. good luck to him..

Comment: oh -1 again, sorry, just found your command won't work. since the cut line (before pipe) has no input file. :) I think the file would be fileB, then the output is just the first column, not the entire line. also if the fileB is that huge, you did expensive processing twice, that could be slow...

Comment: @Kent I fumbled on this badly. I guess I'll just leave it up now that it has the input file at least.

Comment: hey thanks for the help... grep did work. It took around 3 minutes.

Comment: @priyank I guess I was confused on which fields you wanted to match against as Kent pointed out. Glad you found a solution.

Comment: squiguy and @Kent out of curiosity, what would be a better solution?

Comment: @priyank I would say my answer is more generic/safer than that grep solution. since grep does line matching not field/column matching. It is risky for your requirement even if with -F option. My awk one-liner does matching with column, and not with regex, so it would be safe. If you don't like awk, you may do some research on join. I think join could do it  as well. anyway, all these are not important, if the accepted answer solved your problem. good luck.